# arangodb fails to start or upgrade

Tags: arangodb

When I run /etc/init.d/arangodb3 upgrade I get this error

`2018-08-05T13:05:44Z [8290] INFO file-descriptors (nofiles) hard limit is 131072, soft limit is 131072
2018-08-05T13:05:45Z [8290] ERROR duplicate entry for collection name 'test'
2018-08-05T13:05:45Z [8290] ERROR collection id 50339084 has same name as already added collection 50333892
2018-08-05T13:05:45Z [8290] ERROR error while opening database: duplicate name
2018-08-05T13:05:45Z [8290] FATAL cannot start database: duplicate name`

I want know access db and delete 'test' collection but arangoshell now keeps telling me that connection is refused. Anybody have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: As the error says, there are two collections with the same name. This is a corrupted database. How did you get there?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is rather a github issue then something relevant to SO users. The original user didn't reply to questions.